# Command lyapchol in Matlab does not work

Tags: matlab

The command lyapchol in Matlab needs A to have negative eigenvalues so that to compute grammian Wc successfully.

I am trying lyapchol(A, B) , where eigenvalues of A are:

```
-7.702072757196139e+22

-4.204548769720415e+17

-4.132730155685816e+17

-1.469863557258663e+17

-1.341487748044014e+17

-1.245824642151246e+17
```

while the eigenvalues of B are:

```
 3.266756797951905e+30

 5.904640027563640e+29

 1.072475598423812e+28

 3.756253951769876e+27

 2.511451875694431e+14

 1.031563230676382e+14
```

As you can see, all the eigenvalues of A are contained in the left half plane, but Matlab gives me error: 
Error using lyapchol (line 58)
In the "lyapchol(A,B,..)" command, A or (A,E) must have all their eigenvalues in the
left-half plane.
Error in TBR (line 49)
Lc = lyapchol(A_new,B_new)

Error using lyapchol (line 58)
In the "lyapchol(A,B,..)" command, A or (A,E) must have all
their eigenvalues in the left-half plane.
Error in TBR (line 55)
Lc = lyapchol(A,B_new)

> > help lyapchol
> >      lyapchol  Square-root solver for continuous-time Lyapunov equations.

```
R = lyapchol(A,B) computes a Cholesky factorization X = R'*R of 
the solution X to the Lyapunov matrix equation:

    A*X + X*A' + B*B' = 0

All eigenvalues of A must lie in the open left half-plane for R 
to exist.

R = lyapchol(A,B,E) computes a Cholesky factorization X = R'*R of
X solving the generalized Lyapunov equation:

    A*X*E' + E*X*A' + B*B' = 0

All generalized eigenvalues of (A,E) must lie in the open left
half-plane for R to exist.
```

I have a state-space model.

Could anybody please help me or give me any idea why lyapchol does now work properly?
Thank you very much advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** In this solution I have used `eA = eig(A);` and `eB=eig(B);` as you provided in the question.

```
eA =

   1.0e+22 *

  -7.702072757196139
  -0.000042045487697
  -0.000041327301557
  -0.000014698635573
  -0.000013414877480
  -0.000012458246422

eB =

   1.0e+30 *

   3.266756797951905
   0.590464002756364
   0.010724755984238
   0.003756253951770
   0.000000000000000
   0.000000000000000
```

You should make the matrices square, so this works:

```
AA = diag(eA);
BB = diag(eB);
lyapchol(AA,BB)

ans =

   1.0e+20 *

   0.083233469335677                   0                   0                   0                   0                   0
                   0   6.439004539621816                   0                   0                   0                   0
                   0                   0   0.117965196978860                   0                   0                   0
                   0                   0                   0   0.069278972388738                   0                   0
                   0                   0                   0                   0   0.000000000000005                   0
                   0                   0                   0                   0                   0   0.000000000000002
```

If you want the result in the same format as the inputs then get the diagonal values:

```
CC = lyapchol(AA,BB)
diag(CC)

ans =

   1.0e+20 *

   0.083233469335677
   6.439004539621816
   0.117965196978860
   0.069278972388738
   0.000000000000005
   0.000000000000002
```

Comment: I transformed my matrices to square and now something weird is happening :/

Comment: I am getting an error like that: Error using lyapchol (line 38)
In the "lyapchol(A,B)" command, A must be a square matrix.
Error in TBR (line 57)
Lc = lyapchol(AA,BB)

Comment: I am using your data and there is no error. What version of MATLAB do you have? is `size(A) = 6x1`?

Comment: Is there any possibility array A to be unstable although it has negative eigenvalues? Matrix A is the result from the multiplication of two other arrays , so A = -C^-1 * G . However when i get the invert array of C (C^-1) I get a warning "Matrix is singular to working precision" . Does it has any importance ? Does array C is invertible?

Comment: "Matrix is singular to working precision" means that the inverse is not calculated preciesely, however to some specific precision it is good to use. You can check this by `C*C^-1` that has to be `I` the identity matrix. At the end I do not think this would make a difference though.

Comment: I have described above the eigenvalues of array A , not array A. Array A has size 1882*1882.

Comment: Alla values are very close to 1 or exactly 1 , except from one value , which is 7. :/

Comment: So it is a diagonal matrix, however you should check if all the diagonal values are on the left side. Matrix B also should have the same size as matrix A.

Comment: I checked ot through C*C^-1.

Comment: My matrix B has size 1882*5.

Comment: Is the size of eignvalues of `A` and `B` 6x1? If yes, and if they are equal to the values on your post you should not get an error.

Comment: If `B` is not square, how you calculate `eig(B)`? Check my edit, I see that I made you confused :( . If you have the eignvalues you do not need `A` and `B` anymore.

Comment: I calculated eig(B) through svd. In particularly:

Comment: B_transp = B';
B_new = full((-1) * (B * B_transp));
[u1 s1 v1] = svds(B_new);
beig = diag(s1)

Comment: Yes, i don't need A, B in fact anymore, but lyapchol does not work, although we have eigenvalues and they are on the left hand side plane.

Comment: If you have no other data than the two eignvalues provided in the question, it should work as I showed.

Comment: The values I described above are the result which comes from the eig(A), where A is an 1882*1882 matrix, not the same A.

Comment: Command lyapchol is working with the matrices A, B and not their eigenvalues ,right?

Comment: I would like to apply lyapchol command with arguments the matrices A , B , which are of size 1882*1882 and 1882*5 accordingly and not their eigenvalues, as you show me, if I understood it right.

Comment: @EviPanayiotara Why don't you just scale your data? The equation is linear in A and quadratic in B. These numbers don't make too much sense as they are. What kind of a system is this?